# Restrict Lambda URL to specific VPC (for EC2 Instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a few Lambda that are executed from a Jenkins installed on a EC2 instance. I could successfully run a `curl` command from Jenkins to request any of a my Lambda using the URL.

I'd like to secure this architecture with a VPC. My EC2 instance already under the VPC `vpc-001f4912569686a89` so I've put my Lambda under the same one.

I have also created a security group (`sg-0de1a07dd602450f7`) for my Lambda to allow only traffic from my EC2 instance. See the following (`sg-0f62df4def386f83a`) is my EC2 instance's security group) :
[image]

And here is my Lambda VPC configuration:
[image]

From what I understand, this should be enough to get my EC2 to communicate with my Lambda but my `curl` isn't returning me anything (probably a timeout).

**EDIT**

Here is my VPC route table :
[image]

Comment: You can't restrict the invocation of a Lambda function URL to clients in your VPC. Lambda function URLs are public. The correct, and currently only, way to secure them is via IAM.

Answer (score -1):

Your security group setup seems correct.

Please address the following items:

- Could you elaborate on the subnet that your EC2 Instance is running in?
- Your Lambda function's container(s) can spawn in either of the two subnets

  - subnet-053af8185c4f6bbc7
  - subnet-0ac074c5b63e6db9b
- Please check the VPC's route table and ensure traffic can flow between the potential subnets
- Please check the Lambda function's subnets' ACLs to ensure they're not blocking traffic coming from the Jenkins instance

Comment: The subnet used by my EC2 Instance is the same used by my Lambda `subnet-0ac074c5b63e6db9b` and IPV4 `172.31.16.0/20`.

I'm updating my post with the route table.

There is no ACL configured (traffic worked great before configuring VPC in Lambda)

Comment: Lambda function URL endpoints aren't in your VPC. VPC networking and security groups are irrelevant to the invocation of a Lambda function via URL.

Comment: Is it possible to secure a lambda URL using VPC ? 

And are you sure about that ? The moment I setup my VPC in Lambda the URL could not be accessed from Internet (which could before), this seems pretty relevant to me

Comment: What evidence do you have that it could not be invoked? Note that attaching the Lambda function to your VPC changes its outbound networking, so if the Lambda function, for example, makes network requests but has no outbound route then it might timeout or fail. Regardless, however, CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function will show you if it was actually invoked. Please check the logs.

Comment: I was already looking at CloudWatch logs, but I've found out something really weird. I have invoke logs but that are 15-20mn after after making my `curl` call, I don't know what's causing this. 
The outbound rules of my Lambda security group allows everything to go out and my EC2's inbound rule allowing everthing too.

Comment: Lambda function needs to be in private subnet and that subnet needs default route to NAT for the Lambda to be able to reach the internet. It cannot be attached to a public subnet, for example.